# Plot from package "lomb" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the package "lomb" to calculate Lomb-Scargle Periodograms, a method for analysing biological time series data. The package does create a plot if you tell it to do so. However, the plots are not too nice (compared to ggplot2 plots). Therefore, I would like to plot the results with ggplot. However, I do not know how to access the function for the curve plotted...

This is a sample code for a plot:

```
TempDiff <- runif(4033, 3.0, 18) % just generate random numbers
Time2 <- seq(1,4033) % Time vector
Rand.LombScargle <- randlsp(repeats=10, TempDiff, times = Time2, from = 12, to = 36, 
                        type = c("period"), ofac = 10, alpha = 0.01, plot = T, 
                        trace = T, xlab="period", main = "Lomb-Scargle Periodogram")
```

I have also tried to find out something about the function looking into the function randlsp itself, but could not really find anything that seemed useful to me there...

```
 getAnywhere(randlsp)
 A single object matching ‘randlsp’ was found
 It was found in the following places
   package:lomb
   namespace:lomb
 with value

 function (repeats = 1000, x, times = NULL, from = NULL, to = NULL, 
 type = c("frequency", "period"), ofac = 1, alpha = 0.01, 
 plot = TRUE, trace = TRUE, ...) 
  {
    if (is.ts(x)) {
    x = as.vector(x)
  }
 if (!is.vector(x)) {
    times <- x[, 1]
    x <- x[, 2]
}
 if (plot == TRUE) {
    op <- par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
}
 realres <- lsp(x, times, from, to, type, ofac, alpha, plot = plot, 
    ...)
 realpeak <- realres$peak
 pks <- NULL
 if (trace == TRUE) 
    cat("Repeats: ")
 for (i in 1:repeats) {
    randx <- sample(x, length(x))
    randres <- lsp(randx, times, from, to, type, ofac, alpha, 
        plot = F)
    pks <- c(pks, randres$peak)
    if (trace == TRUE) {
        if (i/10 == floor(i/10)) 
            cat(i, " ")
    }
}
if (trace == TRUE) 
    cat("\n")
prop <- length(which(pks >= realpeak))
p.value <- prop/repeats
if (plot == TRUE) {
    mx = max(c(pks, realpeak)) * 1.25
    hist(pks, xlab = "Peak Amplitude", xlim = c(0, mx), main = paste("P-value: ", 
        p.value))
    abline(v = realpeak)
    par(op)
}
res = realres[-(8:9)]
res = res[-length(res)]
res$random.peaks = pks
res$repeats = repeats
res$p.value = p.value
class(res) = "randlsp"
return(invisible(res))
```

Any idea will be appreciated!

Best,
Christine

PS: Here an example of the plot with real data.
[image: Plot with real data]

Comment: for what it's worth, I think the Lomb-Scargle periodogram was originally developed in astrophysics (see Press et al. *Numerical Recipes*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to getting `ggplot` graphs out of any returned object is to convert the data that you need in to some sort of `data.frame`. To do this, you can look at what kind of object your returned value is and see what sort of data you can immediately extract into a `data.frame`

```
str(Rand.LombScargle) # get the data type and structure of the returned value

    List of 12
 $ scanned     : num [1:2241] 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ power       : num [1:2241] 0.759 0.645 0.498 0.341 0.198 ...
 $ data        : chr [1:2] "times" "x"
 $ n           : int 4033
 $ type        : chr "period"
 $ ofac        : num 10
 $ n.out       : int 2241
 $ peak        : num 7.25
 $ peak.at     : num [1:2] 24.6908 0.0405
 $ random.peaks: num [1:10] 4.99 9.82 7.03 7.41 5.91 ...
 $ repeats     : num 10
 $ p.value     : num 0.3
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "randlsp"
```

in the case of `randlsp`, its a list, which is usually what is returned from statistical functions. Most of this information can also be obtained from `?randlsp` too.

It looks as if `Rand.LombScargle$scanned` and `Rand.LombScargle$power` contains most of what is needed for the first graph:

There is also a horizontal line on the Periodogram, but it doesn't correspond to anything that was returned by `randlsp`. Looking at the source code that you provided, it looks as if the Periodogram is actually generated by `lsp()`.

```
LombScargle <- lsp( TempDiff, times = Time2, from = 12, to = 36, 
    type = c("period"), ofac = 10, alpha = 0.01, plot = F)

str(LombScargle)

List of 12
 $ scanned  : num [1:2241] 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ power    : num [1:2241] 0.759 0.645 0.498 0.341 0.198 ...
 $ data     : chr [1:2] "Time2" "TempDiff"
 $ n        : int 4033
 $ type     : chr "period"
 $ ofac     : num 10
 $ n.out    : int 2241
 $ alpha    : num 0.01
 $ sig.level: num 10.7
 $ peak     : num 7.25
 $ peak.at  : num [1:2] 24.6908 0.0405
 $ p.value  : num 0.274
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "lsp"
```

I am guessing that, based on this data, the line is indicating the significance level `LombScargle$sig.level`

Putting this together, we can create our data to pass to `ggplot` from `lsp`:

```
lomb.df <- data.frame(period=LombScargle$scanned, power=LombScargle$power)

# use the data frame to set up the line plot
g <- ggplot(lomb.df, aes(period, power)) + geom_line() + 
       labs(y="normalised power", title="Lomb-Scargle Periodogram")

# add the sig.level horizontal line
g + geom_hline(yintercept=LombScargle$sig.level, linetype="dashed")
```

[image: Periodogram]

For the histogram, it looks like this is based on the vector `Rand.LombScargle$random.peaks` from `randlsp`:

```
rpeaks.df <- data.frame(peaks=Rand.LombScargle$random.peaks)

ggplot(rpeaks.df, aes(peaks)) + 
       geom_histogram(binwidth=1, fill="white", colour="black") + 
       geom_vline(xintercept=Rand.LombScargle$peak, linetype="dashed") +
       xlim(c(0,12)) +  
       labs(title=paste0("P-value: ", Rand.LombScargle$p.value), 
           x="Peak Amplitude", 
           y="Frequency")
```

[image: Histogram]

Play around with these graphs to get them looking to your taste.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks! Your solution really helped me understand how I can solve this and provided me with abilities I will be able to use to approach this kind of questions myself in the future.